# website element is shown in browser, but hidden when i try to reach it using inspect element

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, inspect-element

This is the website https://www.justdial.com/Hyderabad/Wedding-Photographers/nct-10989300, i need to reach phone numbers given on website, but phone number is available on website but when i reach it using the inspect element method nothing is shown in inspect element. I need it to extract phone numbers using xpath.

I need to extract number using xpath, but xpath returns empty string.

```
//p[@class='contact-info ']/span/a
```

xpath should be returning phone number string but it seems its hidden by some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it shows like icons.
See in code:

```
<p class="contact-info " onclick="_ct('clntphn', 'lspg','','040PXX40.XX40.131020024501.A6E5');">
  <i class="res_contactic resultimg"></i>
  <span><a><b>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-dc"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-fe"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-ji"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-yz"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-hg"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-ba"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-ji"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-yz"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-rq"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-wx"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-ts"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-nm"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-vu"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-ts"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-acb"></span>
    <span class="mobilesv icon-yz"></span>
</b></a></span>
```

That **"mobilesv icon-ts"** are actuell your numbers. Just looks for .css icon library for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, so to get number i should converts this by comparing it to library ?

Comment: Actually, yes. But I think, it is not a better way, because in the library you will not see anything special. Nothing, but like ##AADFRT symbols =) But, you can refactor that symbols to numbers. We have only 10 numbers (0,1,2,3...etc..) so, see: *icon-dc* - like *1*, *-fe* like *3*.. etc... =)